# Pivot time series into panel ...python

Tags: python, dataframe, time-series, panel

I have a dataframe with time series on 25 portfolios (ME1_BM1, ME1_BM2, etc.) observed monthly from 1932-02-29 to 2018-07-31. First four observations look like this:

```
                 ME1_BM1     ME1_BM2  ...
Date
1932-02-29       2.11875     1.28388
1932-03-31       2.18567     1.24275
...
```

The Date column is set as the index. I need to prepare the data for something else, so I need to convert the data to something like this:

```
ME1_BM1    1932-02-29    2.11875
           1932-03-31    2.18567
           ...
ME1_BM2    1932-02-29    1.28388
           1932-03-31    1.24275
           ...
```

Cannot make it work. I have tried to stack the dataframe, but then I get the Date as index and the portfolios as second "variable". I got nowhere with pivot as I needed to specify too many variables ...

Anyone know how to do this please ?

Kind regards, Jesper.

Comment: I think panel is not good idea , because it is now [deprecated](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#deprecate-panel)

Comment: Hi - yes, I wrote "panel" to indicate the overall structure of the data I need to end up with, not necessarily a panda functionality. I need to end up with a dataframe in the end.

Comment: Not sure with expected output - do you need 3 columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) for `Series` with `MultiIndex`:

```
s = df.unstack()
print (s)
         Date      
ME1_BM1  1932-02-29    2.11875
         1932-03-31    2.18567
ME1_BM2  1932-02-29    1.28388
         1932-03-31    1.24275
dtype: float64
```

If want 3 columns `DataFrame` add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df1 = df.unstack().reset_index()
df1.columns = ['portfolio','date','val']
print (df1)
  portfolio        date      val
0   ME1_BM1  1932-02-29  2.11875
1   ME1_BM1  1932-03-31  2.18567
2   ME1_BM2  1932-02-29  1.28388
3   ME1_BM2  1932-03-31  1.24275
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the previous answer is more elegant - you can do the following:

```
df = df.reset_index() # so date is not index anymore
```

Melt the portfolios:

```
df2 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=["Date"], value_vars=['ME1_BM1','ME1_BM2'])
```

Apply groupby:

```
df2.groupby(["variable", "Date"])["value"].max()
```

Obviously you can change the column names to make it look a bit more neat.

Also you can just collect all your columns with 
 `df.columns`

remove the date, and then you don't need to type too much.